# Best practices for collaboration

Tags: python, scripting, blend-files

We are working on an internal project with several people on a Blender file. This file serves as a template for a rendering pipeline in which various parameters, objects, etc. are adjusted during processing via the Python API.

The entire project is one big disaster. This is because with different people working together, changes are made to the Blender file that are untraceable, and there are constant misconfigurations due to renaming of materials, and other things.

Question: Are there best practices for team collaboration? How are large projects handled in Blender? What are the recommended best practices? What should be avoided? Is there additional documentation for this specific purpose?

Thanks,
Torsten

Comment: Hello. It's hard to use common version control tools on Blend files because they're binary and the order of lines may be completely mangled on every save ,especially if you use the compressed format. I think the common practice is to use asset linking. Every one works on their specific asset in their file and a manager links everything in a main file or main files. That way changes can be made asynchronously and merged after the fact. But it really depends on the workflow in your team

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I'm just wondering how big projects, like in the movie industry, solves this challenges? Light scene, materials, objects ... It's not possible to generate something like a trace file?

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is too broad to be answerable without requiring an extensive tutorial or description. It also seems to be subjective and attracts opinion based answers rather than facts, because there are no "right" or "wrong" answers and every suggestion is equally valid. For art critique, tips, or other open ended discussions like this it is best to ask over at [Blender Artists](https://blenderartists.org/) or similar forums. If you can rephrase it to focus on objective questions or solving specific issues feel free to [edit] it so it can be reopened.

Comment: It might be worth investigating the [Blender Studio pipeline web site](https://studio.blender.org/pipeline/). I'm not sure whether you can access it without a Blender Studio subscription though.